# android:text issues with @string

Tags: android

I purchased a Beginning Android book and started reading and performing the examples. The very first one says to add code like this:

```
...
...
android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />
```

My question is, are we no longer using the "@string/..."? I get a warning that I should use it, but when I do it turns into a red X. With the warning, it at leasts tries to run but the emulator crashes. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: Show the crash logs, please, as well as any pertinent code. There is nothing wrong with using `@string`, and using them should never crash.

Comment: Eric, these are the log errors.

    [2012-11-05 14:32:20 - Unexpected error while launching logcat.     Try reselecting the device.] device not found
    com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
 at   com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:109)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to be using something along the lines of

```
android:text="@string/copy_here"
```

Then in the strings file use

```
<string name="copy_here">copy here</string>
```

Comment: AJak, that was it. I feel so embarrassed about that mistake. Thank you very much for the hint. I believe this book I purchased is very bad. Eric, thank you as well. I think the errors are with my AVD settings.

Comment: @StephenPaden Darn, I was going to post almost exactly this as an answer, but I figured it would never cause a force-close (just a compile error). But glad it's working! +1 to the answerer. ;)

Comment: No problem! Glad that was the fix for you. If youre looking for a solid book, I would recommend http://commonsware.com/Android/ he keeps it up to date and is very helpful. Also the author has 230k stack overflow reputation, so he probably knows what hes talking about :-)